# c# apply same rules to all textboxes

Tags: c#, textbox, format

I have several text boxes and would like to format them all the same way with these rules:

```
// limits to number, control keys, and decimal
// goes to the next text box when enter
private void tb_text1_KeyPress_1(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    string newString = Regex.Replace(tb_text1.Text, "[^.0-9]", "");
    tb_text1.MaxLength = 6;
    e.Handled = (!char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) && !Char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) && e.KeyChar != '.');
    if (e.KeyChar == (char)(Keys.Enter))
    {
        this.GetNextControl(ActiveControl, true).Focus();
    }
}
// removes restricted chars
private void tb_text1_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    tb_text1.Text = Regex.Replace(tb_text1.Text, "[^.0-9]", "");
}
// applies format at exit
private void tb_text1_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    tb_text1.Text = string.Format("{0,-6} [Ohm]", decimal.Parse(tb_text1.Text));
}
```

What is the best way? create a new text box class based on the text box?
Thanks.

Comment: yes create a new class that is inherited from text box, and override the keypress event

Comment: Thnx Mohammed, override just the keypress event?

Comment: it seems that you have edited the post, No, override all the events used above

Comment: You can use same event handlers to all texboxes, what you need: 
 tb1.KeyPress += tb_text1_KeyPress_1;
 tb2.KeyPress += tb_text1_KeyPress_1;
 etc..

Answer (score 0):

Replace in methods your "tb_text1" variable to the "((TextBox)sender)", and now You can use Your code for any textbox.

Answer (score 0):

It is very easy to do it with javascript . Please try that. I have done it i'm not able to find piece of that code right now . It is worth the effort because it will be very fast and will be running on client side.